# C# .Net file in use issue

Tags: c#, file-io, access-violation

I'm having an issue opening files that have recently been closed by the .Net framework.  Basically, what happens is the following:

- Read in an XML file using `DataSet.ReadXml()`
- Make some changes to the data
- Write out the XML file using `DataSet.WriteXml()`
- Copy the XML file to a new location using `File.Copy`
- FTP the file using a custom control

This sequence can intermittently fail either after the WriteXML or the File.Copy with a file in use exception.
I'm guessing it could be the Windows write cache not flushing right away.  Can anyone confirm that this could be causing my issue?  Any solutions to suggest?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: please post your full sourcecode. we may hunt down this bug :-)

Comment: At the very least post the line with WriteXml, right now we can't see which overload.

Answer (score 1):

Could this possibly be caused by an over eager anti virus program?
They may place a lock on it while they inspect the file

Answer (score 0):

Note: If your using FileStream remember to close it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are opening the file.

I was having the same problem after closing a text file.

This is what I found that worked:

if (null != sReader) ((IDisposable)sReader).Dispose();

where sreader is

StreamReader sReader

Comment: Even better, if you can -- use the 'using' statement so you don't have to think about disposing it.